# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous at $0$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Looking for help on how to get started:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous at $0$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Prove that exists $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)= \langle a,x\rangle$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I don't know how to even start, can I please get a suggestion?

Comment: What does "continuous in o" mean? Do you mean continuous at $0$?

Comment: Prove that $f$ is linear. Then mimic the proof of the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that theorem well. I suppose that I have to proof $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$ and it's enough to say that $f$ is linear, but what should I do after that?

Comment: Look at pages 187-188 of Sheldon Axler’s *Linear Algebra Done Right* (third edition).

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what you mean, but where did I use the hypothesis that $f$ is continuous at $0$? Does that implies that $f$ is linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_j$ be an orthonormal basis, let $a_j = f(e_j)$.

Then $f(e_j) = \left<a,e_j\right>$ by construction.

Now you need to take arbitrary $x = \sum c_j e_j$ and show $f(x) = \sum_j c_j a_j$.

You already have $f(x) = \sum_j f(c_j e_j)$ and so you just need to show that $f(c_j e_j) = c_j f(e_j)$, this is where continuity comes in, i.e. show $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$ as you've suggested.